# Modernizr not detecting capability in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, modernizr

I have downloaded Modernizr and included just one element in the build, the **a[download] Attribute**.

I then included the **modernizr-custom.js** file into my library and added it to my project successfully (no errors):

```
<script src="lib/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
```

I am now attempting to detect if a browser supports the **a download functionality** as described here:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Note, IE and Safari don't support it but Chrome and Firefox do.

I am using the following Javascript code:

```
if (Modernizr.adownload) {
  console.log("SUPPORT");
} else {
  console.log("NO SUPPORT");
}
```

On IE, Firefox and Chrome it shows NO SUPPORT.  As far as I am aware it should show SUPPORT for Firefox and Chrome.

Here are my thoughts:

- Did I not include something I needed to in the build?
- Am I misunderstanding how to test functionality using modernizr?
- Is this a bug in the Modernizr implementation?

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle, a very good idea I will do this in future.

Comment: This page is showing the correct result for each browser. Huh! http://modernizr.github.io/Modernizr/test/

Comment: @ChuckLeButt the test for `adownload` is not included in the modernizr script that you have used in the jsfiddle.

Comment: You probably do not have used a build of modernizr that includes the test for `adownload`. Not all tests are included with the default build. You might want to create a custom build with all test you need to use on the [modernizr.com - download](https://modernizr.com/download) page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```js
/*! modernizr 3.3.1 (Custom Build) | MIT *
 * http://modernizr.com/download/?-adownload-setclasses !*/
!function(e,n,s){function a(e,n){return typeof e===n}function o(){var e,n,s,o,t,i,f;for(var c in r)if(r.hasOwnProperty(c)){if(e=[],n=r[c],n.name&&(e.push(n.name.toLowerCase()),n.options&&n.options.aliases&&n.options.aliases.length))for(s=0;s<n.options.aliases.length;s++)e.push(n.options.aliases[s].toLowerCase());for(o=a(n.fn,"function")?n.fn():n.fn,t=0;t<e.length;t++)i=e[t],f=i.split("."),1===f.length?Modernizr[f[0]]=o:(!Modernizr[f[0]]||Modernizr[f[0]]instanceof Boolean||(Modernizr[f[0]]=new Boolean(Modernizr[f[0]])),Modernizr[f[0]][f[1]]=o),l.push((o?"":"no-")+f.join("-"))}}function t(e){var n=c.className,s=Modernizr._config.classPrefix||"";if(u&&(n=n.baseVal),Modernizr._config.enableJSClass){var a=new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+s+"no-js(\\s|$)");n=n.replace(a,"$1"+s+"js$2")}Modernizr._config.enableClasses&&(n+=" "+s+e.join(" "+s),u?c.className.baseVal=n:c.className=n)}function i(){return"function"!=typeof n.createElement?n.createElement(arguments[0]):u?n.createElementNS.call(n,"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",arguments[0]):n.createElement.apply(n,arguments)}var l=[],r=[],f={_version:"3.3.1",_config:{classPrefix:"",enableClasses:!0,enableJSClass:!0,usePrefixes:!0},_q:[],on:function(e,n){var s=this;setTimeout(function(){n(s[e])},0)},addTest:function(e,n,s){r.push({name:e,fn:n,options:s})},addAsyncTest:function(e){r.push({name:null,fn:e})}},Modernizr=function(){};Modernizr.prototype=f,Modernizr=new Modernizr;var c=n.documentElement,u="svg"===c.nodeName.toLowerCase();Modernizr.addTest("adownload",!e.externalHost&&"download"in i("a")),o(),t(l),delete f.addTest,delete f.addAsyncTest;for(var d=0;d<Modernizr._q.length;d++)Modernizr._q[d]();e.Modernizr=Modernizr}(window,document);

/* Test code */
if (Modernizr.adownload) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "SUPPORT";
} else {
  document.body.innerHTML = "NO SUPPORT";
}
```

Are you sure your custom build includes a[download]? You probably forgot it. [Build from here](https://modernizr.com/download#adownload-setclasses&q=a[download]), and see for yourself.

Comment: Yep, this is right. Strange to me that CDN version doesn't have everything included by default: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxbmJb

Comment: How strange, downloading via your link works fine, yet I did the exact same thing (i really did) and it didn't work (with no errors).  The .js file is exactly the same size and everything, I don't understand that at all.  Thanks